# write unsorted consecutive strings array sorted into a file efficiently

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I have an array of strings containing unordered consecutive numbers (range from 0 to n), e.g. `[7a, 1b, 2c, 0d, 6e, 5f, 3g, 4h]`, and I want to write the numbers in order into a file.

After example:

```
0d
1b
2c
3g
4h
5f
6e
7a
```

The string are not all the same length.

I was trying to find a way to do it both fast and without taking too much space. I found a way that I can do it in O(n) space complexity and O(n) performance: I create an array with n cells and insert each string to his cell number.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   sortedArray[originalArray[i]] = originalArray[i]
```

... something like that (creating new array in the size of the original one and fill it in one run), and then with another for loop write the content of the sorted array into the file.

But I am looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: What is "better"? Space complexity? Time complexity? Time complexity compromising space? Space, compromising time?

Comment: what happen if your n is 2^32 or 2^64? If you have an array of 10 cells with the values between 0 to 2^16, you still need 2^16 operations to print out the "sorted" array. You may claim your algorithm O(n) but it's not really you want.

Comment: Can we rephrase this question to "how to sort such an array" ? Since the file IO is raising many questions.

Comment: Are your strings really 2-chars each, or are they of varying length? This will affect the sort method.

Comment: @WeatherVane they are varying length

Comment: How does this varying length influence the sort order? `1bcdefg` will still appear in the second position, correct?

Comment: @Jongware yes it will

Comment: You should pre-set your array size before populating it, otherwise you will need growing space for the array. Also, inserting each string means you are using a basic insert sort. Why not just go with a merge sort? Or if you have enough elements to justify it, a quick sort?

Comment: @StarPilot the sort described in the question is O(n), which is better than the O(n log n) of a merge sort or quick sort. It's the best-case scenario of a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the leading numbers in your strings are indeed consecutive and non-repeating, you will not achieve better time complexity than than you would with the approach you describe in the question, or something along those lines.  It requires work space proportional to the number of strings.

In comparison,

- a standard merge sort also requires work space proportional to the number of strings (but you can get away with half as much as the approach in the question, if you're careful), and it has `O(n log n)` time complexity.  Alternatively,
- quick sort sorts in-place and has `O(n log n)` time complexity on average; if you implement it carefully then it requires only `O(log n)` work space in the worst case -- a constant amount per stack frame in the recursive version, or a stack accommodating that many elements in a non-recursive one.
- an in-place merge sort requires `O(log n)` work space (and doesn't require as much care to achieve that as does quick sort), and has `O(n^2)` time complexity on average.  It tends to beat most other `O(n^2)` approaches pretty handily, most of the time.
- insertion sort sorts in-place and requires `O(1)` work space, but has `O(n^2)` time complexity.  It's well understood, easy to implement, and very fast in practice for small input sizes.

There are many other alternatives, but I think those are reasonably representative of your options.  Which one best suits your needs depends on the bounds on your problem size, and on how you weigh space vs. speed.  If your problem size can be very large, and you cannot afford `O(n)` space overhead, then give quick sort careful consideration.  If the problem size is certain to be small, but space conservation is critically important, then consider insertion sort.  If high speed is important and you can afford the space overhead, then your original approach is awfully attractive.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that mergesort is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @EOF, *in-place* merge sort has `O(n^2)` average-case time complexity.  An analysis is given [here](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html), for example.  Roughly speaking, the cost arises because `O(n)` elements must be moved, and each move requires a sub-array rotation, with cost proportional to the size of the subarray.

Comment: I think there is an O(n log n) in-place mergesort (but it's not practical): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.5514&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @JuanLopes, that's interesting reading, thanks. I suppose I should clarify that by "in-place merge sort" I meant the common merge-sort algorithm modified to merge in-place. The better-bounded ones described in the literature are rather more esoteric.