# create a new sorted file containing the content of old unsorted file of consecutive numbers efficiently

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, sorting

I have a file containing an unordered sequence of strings (that starts from 0 to n)
and I need to create a new file containing the strings by order
example of the original file 
`4asaa` `1b` `0z` `2ca` `3m` 
the new file will contain the same data but in an ordered sequence (according to the number)
 `0z` `1b` `2ca` `3m` `4asaa` 
I was trying to find an algorithm to do it efficiently but I don't any efficient idea, since it is c language I am trying to minimize the amount of actions on the file (since it is very slow), but if you have any good idea that uses a lot of file action feel free to share.
long story short, I am looking for an efficient way to do it.

Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: You are basically looking for an external sort if file is too big to be loaded to memory, and if it can be loaded to memory - load it, sort in memory, write it (2n file operations)

Comment: here you have a bunch of of sorting algorithms... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: This may help: yesterday's [question from the same course](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30876599/2564301).

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small enough to fit in memory - just load it to RAM, sort it in RAM using any [sorting algorithm that suits you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), and write the sorted array to a new file. This requires only `2n` disk operations (`n` writes and `n` reads).

If your file is too big to fit in memory, use [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) (which is basically a variation of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)) to sort the file with minimal number of disk seeks.